# SSD USB disk not recognized

Tags: usb, ssd

I have a SSD USB disk that I'm using on windows computer which is formated in exFAT.
When plug-in in on my Ubuntu (previously 22.04 and now 23.04) It doesn't recognize it at all.

There are 2 partitions (first is ~20M, the second is multi T). None of them is recognized by any means

When checking with dmesg I receive the following error:

```
[1269372.471862] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[1269372.471871] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[1269372.471875] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
[1269372.471879] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 7a 11 ff e0 00 00 01 00
[1269372.471881] critical target error, dev sdf, sector 16383999744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[1269372.471889] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf2, logical block 2047995872, async page read
```

I do not know what to do anymore to understand where is the issue.

I've tried to reformat the drive in NTFS, but the issue is the same.

Thank you for any help